# How to redirect from http to https with and without www and have canonical url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

this may have been asked before but I just want to be sure that it is correct in my case.

Basically i have few errors on PageChecking interfaces that i may have 2 pages available which may duplicate content. Currently i have HTTPS redirect from basic HTTP.

Although I need a redirect that redirects www to non www https and keeps the non-www adress and adds https.

This is how my htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.ownedcore/upl/usr/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.bananaforum.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.dafont.com/[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://goingsony.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://i.imgur.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.wallpapervortex.com/ [NC]

RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

These rewritecond with other urls are probably irrelevant so just let me know what shall I delete and fix please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified rules on the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.ownedcore/upl/usr/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.bananaforum.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.dafont.com/[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://goingsony.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://i.imgur.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.wallpapervortex.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, although in a SEO check report i still get an warning message that: 
Warning, no 301 redirects are in place to redirect traffic to your preferred domain. Pages that load successfully both with and without www. are treated as duplicate content!

 Not all versions of your page point to the same URL.    UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE     Is this something i should really care for?